# Clang-CL warning strnicmp is deprecated, use ISO C and C++ conformant name _strnicmp

Tags: c++

Using `strnicmp()` on Windows with Clang-CL gives this warning:

```
main.cpp(176,12):  warning: 'strnicmp' is deprecated: The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _strnicmp. See online help for details. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

Now, I would gladly just use `_strnicmp()`, but I can find nowhere that this function is actually part of ISO C or the C++ standard. The [cppreference](http://cppreference.com/) does not list it and searching with Google just gets you to the [Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chd90w8e.aspx).

Is this function actually safe to use (ie. part of a C/C++ standard)? If not, why does Clang advertise it as such?

Comment: _"...the identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers  So `_strnicmp` is reserved for implementation use.

Comment: You wanted to use strnicmp, which is not a part of the standard either. Why be selective about it?

Comment: @n.m. I am not asking about a standard function -- I am asking why clang is falsely advertising it to be part of the standard (or I may have a misunderstanding what they mean with "ISO C and C++ conformant name").

Comment: "clang is falsely advertising it to be part of the standard". Clang is doing no such thing. It says `_strnicmp` is *standard conformant*, which it is. "Standard conformant" doesn't mean "is a part of the standard", it means "does not violate the standard". `strnicmp` is not standard conformant, because all names that start with `str` are reserved for the implementation (if you include the relevant header).

Comment: And by the way clang proper has nothing to do with it, the warning is given by the Microsoft's standard library.

Comment: Correction: names that start with `str` <s>are reserved for the implementation</s> may be added to the standard in the future, which means neither implementations nor user code should not use such names. More importantly, names that are neither mentioned in the standard nor are reserved for the implementation *cannot* be declared by standard headers. This means `strnicmp` is not standard conformant, while `_strnicmp` is (because it's reserved).

Answer (score 3):

That's kind of the point, the leading underscore is to mark the function as *not* part of standard C, because it's not.

It is however available in Windows, so as long as you don't care about portability then use `_strnicmp` as much as you want.

If you *do* want portability, then I suggest you make a wrapper function that calls `_strnicmp` on Windows, and other similar function on other platforms (like e.g. [`strncasecmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncasecmp.html) on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS).

Comment: I went a step further and implemented `strncasecmp` and it's friends in `compat.c` and included it in most of our projects.  A macro would work as long as you don't use pointers to the function.